# jQuery Function stops working when there is multiple targets but works when there is one target

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make validate my shopping cart when the quantity is changed to zero, as I am basically hiding the minus icon when the html equals zero, it works whenever I have one item in my cart, but stops working when there are multiple items, would anyone know why this is?

In my blade file I have this for each item

```
<td data-th="Quantity">
  <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" data-id="{{$id}}"></i> <span class="quantity-val quantity-{{$id}}">{{ $details['quantity'] }} </span> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-id="{{$id}}"></i> 
</td>
```

and in my JS file I have this function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            initialQuantity = $('.quantity-val').text();

            if(initialQuantity == 0){
                $(".fa-minus-circle").hide();
            }

        });
```

Would anyone know why this is?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, but `$('.quantity-val').text()` gets you the text content from only the very first matching element.

Comment: `$('.quantity-val').text();` <- what value are you looking for, if there are several of them? You probably want a loop, using `$.each`.

Comment: Ahh of course, how could I write this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over each corresponding cell, and [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings) to retrieve the corresponding "minus" icons:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quantity-val').each(function() {
    var initialQuantity = parseInt($(this).text());
    if (initialQuantity === 0) {
      $(this).siblings('.fa-minus-circle').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
      <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" data-id="1"></i> <span class="quantity-val quantity-1">10</span> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-id="1"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
      <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" data-id="2"></i> <span class="quantity-val quantity-1">0</span> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-id="2"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works, thanks Jeto! I had it in my each function, that all minuses disappeared not the selected one only